# Azure Cosmos DB secret connection strings per database

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

in my Azure Cosmos DB account, I can add multiple databases (containing multiple collections).

However, I only seem to find account-level connection strings (secrets), that are valid for each database. Differing only in the database name section.

I find this odd. Is this expected? If I want more granular control do I need to create separate accounts for each database?

PS: I'm using the Mongo API if it's somehow relevant.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account-level connection strings you mentioned in the question is master key.Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data), Azure Cosmos DB uses two types of keys to authenticate users and provide access to its data and resources.

[image]

Master keys cannot be used to provide granular access to containers and documents.

[image]

If you want more granular control,please get an idea of Resource Tokens which provides access to specific containers, partition keys, documents, attachments, stored procedures, triggers, and UDFs.More details,please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data#resource-tokens).